# ASP.NET MVC DropDownList causes postbacks which I don't expect - seems to origin from JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a standard form in my MVC project, where I have a DropDownList. When I change the value of the dropdownlist, the whole pages reloads as it results in a postback.

I do not expect this behavior, and I am trying to stop the dropdownlist for doing a postback.

However, this is where it gets weird. I define my dropdownlist in the following way:

```
@Html.DropDownList("sortOrder", null, new { onchange = "startUpdate(this)" })
```

Ignoring Javascipt, there is nothing that would expect me to make a postback. If we include the whole form, we can see that is the case as well here:

```
 @using (var form = Html.BeginForm("Query", "Search", FormMethod.Get, new { id="queryform", name="queryform", onsubmit = "startUpdate(this); return false;"}))
                    {

                                <b>Sorter efter</b><br />
                                @Html.DropDownList("sortOrder", null, new { onchange = "startUpdate(this)" })<br />
                            </div>
                            <br />
                        <input type="submit" class="button_green" value="Søg igen &#x25BA;" id="SearchButton" name="SearchButton" style="float: left;" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Ads_listing', 'search_again_click']); startUpdate(this); return false;" />
                        <input type="reset" class="button_small" value="Nulstil" id="ClearButton" style="float: right;" />
                        </text>
                    }
```

However, now a smart person might say:

> "try to disable JavaScript, and see what happens"

So I did. And then the postback did NOT happen. So my problem, most likely, originates from some JavaScript.

Only problem? I cannot seem to find it.

I have cleared all JavaScript I could imagine that have ANYTHING to do with it, yet it still gives me  a postback.

So, sorry, I have to include all my rendered markup, in the hopes that you guys can help me with this big problem (the select html element is called `sortOrder`):

(I could not copy whole HTML, so I removed some sections - a production version can be seen at http://www.amino.dk/virksomhedsbors/search/query?transactionType=2&text=&sectorList=&priceFrom=&priceTo= )

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang=&quot;da-dk&quot;> 
    <head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8" /> 
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /> 
    <title>Virksomheder til salg</title> 
    <script type="text/javascript">var _sf_startpt = (new Date()).getTime()</script> 
    <link href="/styles/saxis.min.css?v=1" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 

    <link target="_blank" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,900" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
    <link href="http://www.amino.dk/virksomhedsbors/rss.aspx" rel="alternate" title="Virksomheder købes og sælges" type="application/rss+xml" /> 
    <link href="http://www.amino.dk/virksomhedsbors/rss.aspx?type=buy" rel="alternate" title="Virksomheder købes" type="application/rss+xml" /> 
    <link href="http://www.amino.dk/virksomhedsbors/rss.aspx?type=sell" rel="alternate" title="Virksomheder til salg" type="application/rss+xml" /> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.js"></script> 

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script> 

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://eas4.emediate.eu/EAS_tag.1.0.js"></script> 

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Assets/js/global.js?2.0"></script> 

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/user/infobox?635467592356980146"></script> 



    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function () { 
    $.ajaxSetup( 
    { cache: false } 
    ); 
    } 
    ); 
    </script> 
    <style type="text/css"> 
    <!-- 
    .cell { 
    padding-left: 15px; 
    } 
    --> 
    </style> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 

    var _gaq = _gaq || []; 
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-10494982-1']); 
    _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', '.amino.dk']); 



    _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'Medlemstype', 'Ikke registreret', 1]); 
    _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 2, 'VB-type', 'Ikke registreret', 1]); 

    document.referrer.match(/https?:\/\/[^/]*google\..*[?&]cd=([^&]*)/gi); 
    var gaqgr = RegExp.$1; 
    if (gaqgr) { 
    _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 3, 'GoogleRank', gaqgr, 2]); 
    } 


    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']); 



    _gaq.push(['_trackPageLoadTime']); 

    (function () { 
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true; 
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js'; 
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s); 
    })(); 



    </script> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
    <div id="background_body"> 

    <div id="topad" style="clear: both; text-align: center; margin: 0 auto 10px"> 
    <div id="EAS_c13cb956" style="width:930px;height:180px;margin:0 auto;border:0;padding:0;"></div> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() { 
    EAS_load_fif("EAS_c13cb956", "/EAS_fif.html", "http://eas4.emediate.eu/eas?cu=1202;cre=mu;js=y;target=_blank;ord=635467592356990147", 930, 180); 
    }); 
    </script> 

    </div> 

    </div> 
    </div> 
    <div id="body"> 
    <div id="contentBody"> 

    <div id="sidead" style="position: fixed; width: 300px; height: 600px; margin-left: 963px; top:180px;"> 
    <div id="EAS_5408e9fb" style="width:300px;height:600px;margin:0 auto 0 0;border:0;padding:0;"></div> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() { 
    EAS_load_fif("EAS_5408e9fb", "/EAS_fif.html", "http://eas4.emediate.eu/eas?cu=13120;cre=mu;js=y;target=_blank;ord=635467592359750304", 300, 600); 
    }); 
    </script> 
    </div> 



    <div id="UserInformation" style="display: none;"></div> 




    <div class="column left" style="width: 698px;"> 
    <div class="contentBoxtitle2"> 
    <span style="float: right; margin-right: 5px; margin-top: 5px;" id="SAAdd" class="SearchAgentButton"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick=" _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Ads_listing', 'add_searchagent_click']); addSearchAgent(); ">Tilføj som søgeagent</a></span> 
    <h1 class="contentBoxtitle_home" style="width: 395px; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;" id="searchtitle">Virksomheder til salg</h1> 
    </div> 
    <div id="searchResults"> 


    <div class="contentBoxSubtitle2"> 
    <h2> 
    Viser <u>1</u> til <u>30</u> af i alt <u>1383</u> 


    <div style="float: right;"> 

    << Forrige 
    | 
    1 | 
    <a href="/search/query?transactiontype=2&amp;pagesize=30&amp;pageno=2&amp;sortorder=0">2</a> 
    | 
    <a href="/search/query?transactiontype=2&amp;pagesize=30&amp;pageno=3&amp;sortorder=0">3</a> 
    | 
    <a href="/search/query?transactiontype=2&amp;pagesize=30&amp;pageno=4&amp;sortorder=0">4</a> 
    | 
    <a href="/search/query?transactiontype=2&amp;pagesize=30&amp;pageno=5&amp;sortorder=0">5</a> 
    | 
    <a href="/search/query?transactiontype=2&amp;pagesize=30&amp;pageno=6&amp;sortorder=0">6</a> 
    | 
    <a href="/search/query?transactiontype=2&amp;pagesize=30&amp;pageno=7&amp;sortorder=0">7</a> 
    | 
    <a href="/search/query?transactiontype=2&amp;pagesize=30&amp;pageno=2&amp;sortorder=0">Næste &gt;&gt;</a> 
    &nbsp; 




    </div> 
    </h2> 
    </div> 
    <div class="contentBox2"> 

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    var sortLink = "/search/query?transactionType=2&amp;text=&amp;priceFrom=&amp;priceTo=&amp;yearFrom=&amp;yearTo=&amp;saleReasons=&amp;canMove=&amp;regions=&amp;operatingRegions=&amp;allOperatingRegionsRequired=&amp;sectors=&amp;allSectorsRequired=&amp;financingAvailable=&amp;country=&amp;pageSize=30&amp;sortOrder={sortOrder}&amp;"; 
    </script> 

    <div style="text-align: right; margin-bottom: 3px;">Sorter efter <select id="order" name="order" onchange="top.location.href=sortLink.replace(&quot;{sortOrder}&quot;, this.value); "><option selected="selected" value="0">Relevans</option> 
    <option value="1">Oprettelsesdato (nyeste f&#248;rst)</option> 
    <option value="2">Oprettelsesdato (&#230;ldste f&#248;rst)</option> 
    <option value="3">Redigeringsdato (nyeste f&#248;rst)</option> 
    <option value="4">Redigeringsdato (&#230;ldste f&#248;rst)</option> 
    <option value="5">Pris (h&#248;jeste f&#248;rst)</option> 
    <option value="6">Pris (laveste f&#248;rst)</option> 
    </select></div> 

    <div class="silverbox even" style=""> 
    <div class="ribbon silver"></div> 
    <p class="adtitle"> 
    <a href="/saelges/handel/agenturhandel/btb-og-btc-udklaedning-legetoej-og-kostumer-inkl-varelager-til-salg-19115">BtB og BtC Udklædning, legetøj og kostumer inkl varelager til salg</a> 

    <img src="/images/icon_unlock20x25.png" alt="Du kan kontakte denne annonce" style="width: 20px; height: 25px; border: none;" /> 
    </p> 
    <p class="regions">Midtjylland</p> 
    <div class="price"><span class="pricelabel">Udbudspris:</span> <span class="pricevalue">895.000 DKK</span></div> 
    <div class="category"><span class="categorylabel">Forretningsområde:</span> <span class="categoryvalue">Agenturhandel</span></div> 
    <p class="description">Velkendt engros firma der handler med udklædning, kostumer og legetøj. Mange faste kunder spredt over hele landet giver en god stabil omsætning. Salget foregår via hjemmeside og kundebesøg<b>...</b></p> 
    <p class="seemore"> 
    Se flere virksomheder til salg inden for:<br /> 
    <a href="/saelges/handel/agenturhandel">Agenturhandel</a> 

    </p> 
    <p class="date" style="float: right; clear: both; text-align: right;"> 
    Senest redigeret 16-09-2014 
    </p> 
    </div> 
    <br /> 
    <br /> 

    </div> 

    <div class="contentBoxSubtitle2"> 
    <h2> 
    Viser <u>1</u> til <u>30</u> af i alt <u>1383</u> 
    <div style="float: right;"> 

    << Forrige 
    | 
    1 | 
    <a href="/search/query?transactiontype=2&amp;pagesize=30&amp;pageno=2&amp;sortorder=0">2</a> 
    | 
    <a href="/search/query?transactiontype=2&amp;pagesize=30&amp;pageno=3&amp;sortorder=0">3</a> 
    | 
    <a href="/search/query?transactiontype=2&amp;pagesize=30&amp;pageno=4&amp;sortorder=0">4</a> 
    | 
    <a href="/search/query?transactiontype=2&amp;pagesize=30&amp;pageno=5&amp;sortorder=0">5</a> 
    | 
    <a href="/search/query?transactiontype=2&amp;pagesize=30&amp;pageno=6&amp;sortorder=0">6</a> 
    | 
    <a href="/search/query?transactiontype=2&amp;pagesize=30&amp;pageno=7&amp;sortorder=0">7</a> 
    | 
    <a href="/search/query?transactiontype=2&amp;pagesize=30&amp;pageno=2&amp;sortorder=0">Næste &gt;&gt;</a> 
    &nbsp; 




    </div> 
    </h2> 
    </div> 
    </div> 
    <div class="contentBoxFooter2"></div> 
    </div> 
    <div class="column"> 
    <div class="box"> 
    <p class="title">Indskrænk/ændre søgning</p> 
    <div class="boxbody"> 

    <form action="/search/query" id="queryform" method="get" name="queryform" onsubmit=" return false;"> 
    Din rolle er:<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp; <input checked="checked" id="trsBuyer" name="transactionType" onclick="startUpdate(this)" type="radio" value="2" />&nbsp;<label for="trsBuyer">Køber</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input id="trsSeller" name="transactionType" onclick="startUpdate(this)" type="radio" value="1" />&nbsp;<label for="trsSeller">Sælger</label><br /> 
    <br /> 
    <b>Søgeord:</b><br /> 
    <input id="text" name="text" onkeypress="startUpdate(this)" onkeyup="startUpdate(this)" style="width: 210px;" type="text" value="" /><br /> 
    <br /> 
    <b>Forretningsområder:</b><br /> 
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick=" $(this).hide(500); $('#secadv').show(500); ">Avanceret &#x25ba;</a><span id="secadv" style="display: none;"><input id="allSectorsRequired" name="allSectorsRequired" onclick=" " style="margin-top: 2px;" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="allSectorsRequired" type="hidden" value="false" /> <label for="allSectorsRequired">Alle er påkrævet (OG-søgning)</label></span> 
    <input type="checkbox" onclick=" " name="sectors" value="12" id="sector12" /> 
    <label for="sector12"> Transportmiddelindustri</label></div> 
    </div> 
    </div> 


    <br /> 
    <a id="showadvprops" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick=" _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Ads_listing', 'search_advanced_criteria']); showAdvancedProps(); ">Vis avancerede kriterier &#x25ba;</a> 
    <a id="hideadvprops" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick=" showAdvancedProps(); " style="display: none;">Skjul avancerede kriterier &#x25c4;</a><br /> 
    <br /> 
    <div id="advsearch" style="display: none;"> 
    <b>Beliggenhed:</b><br /> 
    <div style="height: 100px; overflow: auto; border: 1px solid #999; padding: 1px 1px 1px 1px; margin-top: 2px;"> 

    <div style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; height: 18px; line-height: 18px;" title="Nordjylland"> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="regions" onclick=" " value="1" id="region1" /> 
    <label for="region1"> Nordjylland</label></div> 
    <div style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; height: 18px; line-height: 18px;" title="Midtjylland"> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="regions" onclick=" " value="2" id="region2" /> 
    <label for="region2"> Midtjylland</label></div> 
    <div style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; height: 18px; line-height: 18px;" title="Syd- og S&#248;nderjylland"> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="regions" onclick=" " value="3" id="region3" /> 
    <label for="region3"> Syd- og S&#248;nderjylland</label></div> 
    <div style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; height: 18px; line-height: 18px;" title="Fyn"> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="regions" onclick=" " value="4" id="region4" /> 
    <label for="region4"> Fyn</label></div> 
    <div style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; height: 18px; line-height: 18px;" title="Sj&#230;lland, &#216;erne og Bornholm"> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="regions" onclick=" " value="5" id="region5" /> 
    <label for="region5"> Sj&#230;lland, &#216;erne og Bornholm</label></div> 
    <div style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; height: 18px; line-height: 18px;" title="Stork&#248;benhavn"> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="regions" onclick=" " value="6" id="region6" /> 
    <label for="region6"> Stork&#248;benhavn</label></div> 
    <div style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; height: 18px; line-height: 18px;" title="Ikke oplyst"> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="regions" onclick=" " value="7" id="region7" /> 
    <label for="region7"> Ikke oplyst</label></div> 
    <div style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; height: 18px; line-height: 18px;" title="Hele landet"> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="regions" onclick=" " value="8" id="region8" /> 
    <label for="region8"> Hele landet</label></div> 
    <div style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; height: 18px; line-height: 18px;" title="Udlandet"> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="regions" onclick=" " value="9" id="region9" /> 
    <label for="region9"> Udlandet</label></div> 
    </div> 

    <br /> 
    <b>Opererer i:</b><br /> 
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick=" $(this).hide(500); $('#regadv').show(500); ">Avanceret &#x25ba;</a><span id="regadv" style="display: none;"><input id="allOperatingRegionsRequired" name="allOperatingRegionsRequired" onclick=" " style="margin-top: 2px;" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="allOperatingRegionsRequired" type="hidden" value="false" /> <label for="allOperatingRegionsRequired">Alle er påkrævet (OG-søgning)</label></span> 
    <div style="height: 100px; overflow: auto; border: 1px solid #999; padding: 1px 1px 1px 1px; margin-top: 2px;"> 
    <div style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; height: 18px; line-height: 18px;" title="Nordjylland"> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="operatingRegions" onclick=" " value="1" id="operatingregion1" /> 
    <label for="operatingregion1"> Nordjylland</label></div> 
    <div style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; height: 18px; line-height: 18px;" title="Midtjylland"> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="operatingRegions" onclick=" " value="2" id="operatingregion2" /> 
    <label for="operatingregion2"> Midtjylland</label></div> 
    <div style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; height: 18px; line-height: 18px;" title="Syd- og S&#248;nderjylland"> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="operatingRegions" onclick=" " value="3" id="operatingregion3" /> 
    <label for="operatingregion3"> Syd- og S&#248;nderjylland</label></div> 
    <div style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; height: 18px; line-height: 18px;" title="Fyn"> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="operatingRegions" onclick=" " value="4" id="operatingregion4" /> 
    <label for="operatingregion4"> Fyn</label></div> 
    <div style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; height: 18px; line-height: 18px;" title="Sj&#230;lland, &#216;erne og Bornholm"> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="operatingRegions" onclick=" " value="5" id="operatingregion5" /> 
    <label for="operatingregion5"> Sj&#230;lland, &#216;erne og Bornholm</label></div> 
    <div style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; height: 18px; line-height: 18px;" title="Stork&#248;benhavn"> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="operatingRegions" onclick=" " value="6" id="operatingregion6" /> 
    <label for="operatingregion6"> Stork&#248;benhavn</label></div> 
    <div style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; height: 18px; line-height: 18px;" title="Ikke oplyst"> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="operatingRegions" onclick=" " value="7" id="operatingregion7" /> 
    <label for="operatingregion7"> Ikke oplyst</label></div> 
    <div style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; height: 18px; line-height: 18px;" title="Hele landet"> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="operatingRegions" onclick=" " value="8" id="operatingregion8" /> 
    <label for="operatingregion8"> Hele landet</label></div> 
    <div style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; height: 18px; line-height: 18px;" title="Udlandet"> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="operatingRegions" onclick=" " value="9" id="operatingregion9" /> 
    <label for="operatingregion9"> Udlandet</label></div> 
    </div> 


    <br /> 
    <b>Prisinterval:</b><br /> 
    <input id="priceFrom" name="priceFrom" onkeypress=" " onkeyup=" " style="width: 75px;" type="text" value="" /> til <input id="priceTo" name="priceTo" onkeypress=" " onkeyup=" " style="width: 75px;" type="text" value="" /> 
    <br /> 
    <br /> 
    <b>Etableringsår:</b><br /> 
    <input id="yearFrom" name="yearFrom" onkeypress=" " onkeyup=" " style="width: 75px;" type="text" value="" /> til <input id="yearTo" name="yearTo" onkeypress=" " onkeyup=" " style="width: 75px;" type="text" value="" /> 
    <br /> 
    <br /> 
    <b>Virksomheden skal kunne flyttes:</b><br /> 
    <input checked="checked" id="canMoveNI" name="canMove" onclick=" " type="radio" value="" /> <label for="canMoveNI">Ikke vigtigt</label><br /> 
    <input id="canMoveNo" name="canMove" onclick=" " type="radio" value="0" /> <label for="canMoveNo">Nej</label><br /> 
    <input id="canMoveYes" name="canMove" onclick=" " type="radio" value="1" /> <label for="canMoveYes">Ja</label><br /> 
    <br /> 
    <b>Sælgerfinansiering skal tilbydes:</b><br /> 
    <input checked="checked" id="financingAvailableNI" name="financingAvailable" onclick=" " type="radio" value="" /> <label for="financingAvailableNI">Ikke vigtigt</label><br /> 
    <input id="financingAvailableNo" name="financingAvailable" onclick=" " type="radio" value="0" /> <label for="financingAvailableNo">Nej</label><br /> 
    <input id="financingAvailableYes" name="financingAvailable" onclick=" " type="radio" value="1" /> <label for="financingAvailableYes">Ja</label><br /> 
    <br /> 
    <b>Sorter efter</b><br /> 
    <select id="sortOrder" name="sortOrder" onchange=" "><option selected="selected" value="0">Relevans</option> 
    <option value="1">Oprettelsesdato (nyeste f&#248;rst)</option> 
    <option value="2">Oprettelsesdato (&#230;ldste f&#248;rst)</option> 
    <option value="3">Redigeringsdato (nyeste f&#248;rst)</option> 
    <option value="4">Redigeringsdato (&#230;ldste f&#248;rst)</option> 
    <option value="5">Pris (h&#248;jeste f&#248;rst)</option> 
    <option value="6">Pris (laveste f&#248;rst)</option> 
    </select><br /> 
    </div> 
    <br /> 
    <input type="submit" class="button_green" value="Søg igen &#x25BA;" id="SearchButton" name="SearchButton" style="float: left;" onclick=" _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Ads_listing', 'search_again_click']); return false; " /> 
    <input type="reset" class="button_small" value="Nulstil" id="ClearButton" style="float: right;" /> 

    </form> </div> 

    <div class="boxfooter"></div> 
    </div> 

    <br /> 
    <div id="EAS_f01c93ec" style="width:240px;height:auto;margin:0 auto;border:0;padding:0;"></div> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() { 
    EAS_load_fif("EAS_f01c93ec", "/EAS_fif.html", "http://eas4.emediate.eu/eas?cu=1193;cre=mu;js=y;target=_blank;ord=635467592356970145", 240, 400); 
    }); 
    </script> 



    </div> 







    <div style="clear: both;"></div> 
    <br /> 


    <div id="bottomad" style="clear: both; text-align: center; margin: 0 auto 10px"> 
    <div id="EAS_3b18704e" style="width:930px;height:180px;margin:0 auto;border:0;padding:0;"></div> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() { 
    EAS_load_fif("EAS_3b18704e", "/EAS_fif.html", "http://eas4.emediate.eu/eas?cu=9947;cre=mu;js=y;target=_blank;ord=635467592359760305", 930, 180); 
    }); 
    </script> 

    </div> 



    <div class="contentHeader"></div> 
    <div class="CommonContentBox"> 
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.amino.dk/content/amino-partners.js"></script> 

    </div> 
    <div class="contentFooter"></div> 


    </div> 

    <div style="clear: both;"></div> 


    </div> 

    <!-- (C)2000-2009 Gemius SA - gemiusAudience / amino.dk / Virksomhedsbors --> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    <!-- //--><![CDATA[//><!-- 
    //modified 2013-02-11 rjs as per user specs. updates on gemius 
    var pp_gemius_identifier = 'bQ0w24csi_1RJcq7a4IMCqdFHWxgAe_a9eJp1cOw7Gf.f7'; 
    (function (d, t) { 
    var ex; try { 
    var 
    gt = d.createElement(t), s = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0], l = 'http' + ((location.protocol == 'https:') ? 's' : ''); 
    gt.async = 'true'; gt.src = l + '://gadk.hit.gemius.pl/xlgemius.js'; s.parentNode.insertBefore(gt, s); 
    } catch (ex) 
    { } 
    }(document, 'script')); 
    //end modified 2013-02-11 rjs as per user specs. updates on gemius 
    //--><!]]> 
    </script> 

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    var _sf_async_config = { uid: 17411, domain: "amino.dk" }; 
    (function () { 
    function loadChartbeat() { 
    window._sf_endpt = (new Date()).getTime(); 
    var e = document.createElement('script'); 
    e.setAttribute('language', 'javascript'); 
    e.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript'); 
    e.setAttribute('src', 
    (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://a248.e.akamai.net/chartbeat.download.akamai.com/102508/" : "http://static.chartbeat.com/") + 
    "js/chartbeat.js"); 
    document.body.appendChild(e); 
    } 
    var oldonload = window.onload; 
    window.onload = (typeof window.onload != 'function') ? 
    loadChartbeat : function () { oldonload(); loadChartbeat(); }; 
    })(); 

    </script> 

    <!-- Visual Studio Browser Link --> 
    <script type="application/json" id="__browserLink_initializationData"> 
    {"appName":"Chrome","requestId":"048073e31ed74ed68eeda96481c8bd4e"} 
    </script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:47739/1a675c31cef44fcca8dc0704a89a9da5/browserLink" async="async"></script> 
    <!-- End Browser Link --> 

    </body> 
    </html>
```

I am lost. I have been searching for hours now, and I cannot find that stupid JS that causes the postback. ANY ideas? It would be a tremendous help.

**EDIT:**

In the code, the startUpdate is refered. I tried to delete it, and I still got postback. Here is the code though:

```
 function startUpdate(sender) {
            if (tmr != null) clearTimeout(tmr);
            tmr = setTimeout("updateSearch()", 700);
        }

        function updateSearch() {
            tmr = null;
            searchParams.transactiontype = $("input[name=transactionType]:checked").val();
            searchParams.text = $("input[name=text]").val();
            var sct = "";
            $("input[name=sectors]:checked").each(function() { sct += $(this).val() + ","; });
            searchParams.sector = sct;
            searchParams.allsectorsrequired = $("#allSectorsRequired").attr("checked") == "checked" ? "true" : "";
            var rgn = "";
            $("input[name=regions]:checked").each(function() { rgn += $(this).val() + ","; });
            searchParams.region = rgn;
            var orgn = "";
            $("input[name=operatingRegions]:checked").each(function() { orgn += $(this).val() + ","; });
            searchParams.operatingregion = orgn;
            searchParams.alloperatingregionsrequired = $("#allOperatingRegionsRequired").attr("checked") == "checked" ? "true" : "";
            searchParams.priceFrom = $("input[name=priceFrom]").val();
            searchParams.priceTo = $("input[name=priceTo]").val();
            searchParams.yearFrom = $("input[name=yearFrom]").val();
            searchParams.yearTo = $("input[name=yearTo]").val();
            searchParams.canMove = $("input[name=canMove]:checked").val();
            searchParams.financingavailable = $("input[name=financingAvailable]:checked").val();
            searchParams.orderby = $("select[name=sortOrder]").val();

            for (var key in searchParams) {
                if ((!psp || psp[key] != searchParams[key]) && searchParams[key]) {
                    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Vbørs Søg autoupdate', key, searchParams[key]]);
                }
            }
            psp = $.extend({}, searchParams);

            $("#searchResults").load("@Url.Action("SearchJSON", "Search")", searchParams, searchCallback);

            var tttxt = " til salg";
            if (searchParams.transactiontype != 2) tttxt = " købes";

            if (searchParams.text.length > 0) {
                $("#searchtitle").text(searchParams.text + tttxt);
                document.title = searchParams.text + tttxt;
            }
        }
```

Comment: StartUpdate(this) - where is it?

Comment: onchange = "startUpdate(this)" is calling the javascript, but i don't see that method directly on the page anywhere, so it have to exist in one of these files.    "/Assets/js/global.js?2.0" or "/user/infobox?635467592356980146"

Comment: Hey guys :) The code i pasted, is a version where I tried to remove ALL JavaScript (removing the method did nothing and I still got postbacks). You can see the method on production at the following link:
http://www.amino.dk/virksomhedsbors/search/query?transactionType=2&text=&sectorList=&priceFrom=&priceTo=

Comment: Open the browser console window and check on the Network tab to see what's being called.

Comment: @MelanciaUK it makes a GET to the same URL - however, that is the problem - it should not make a GET! If the GET is made as AJAX, it is OK, but it should not redirect the page. You can try yourself by changing the select/option on http://www.amino.dk/virksomhedsbors/search/query?transactionType=2&amp;text=&amp;priceFrom=&amp;priceTo=&amp;yearFrom=&amp;yearTo=&amp;saleReasons=&amp;canMove=&amp;regions=&amp;operatingRegions=&amp;allOperatingRegionsRequired=&amp;sectors=&amp;allSectorsRequired=&amp;financingAvailable=&amp;country=&amp;pageSize=30&amp;sortOrder=2&amp;

Comment: It's definitely the handler attached to the change event.

Comment: If you inspect the `select`, you'll note this code `onchange="top.location.href=sortLink.replace("{sortOrder}", this.value);"`. This is a GET of some sort.

Comment: @MelanciaUK You are right!!! :) thanks! please post an answer - so helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what I posted in the comments, somehow (you may know where this is happening in your code) your `onchange` event handler is being changed, from `startUpdate(this)` to `top.location.href=sortLink.replace("{sortOrder}", this.value);`.

So, when the `select` changes, it's replacing the page URL, which obviously cause a refresh (by GET).